# Can list objects in s3 bucket but can't download

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to move files between cross account s3 buckets.
I am able to list all objects in the source bucket and list all files in a particular directory in that bucket but I am not able to download the files. I am using python with boto3

```
    client = boto3.client('s3')

    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    folder = 'folder1/folder2/2018/04/01/'
        def my_keys(bucket,folder):
            keys = []
            response = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=folder)
            for obj in response['Contents']:
                keys.append(obj['Key'])
            return keys
        
        
        files = my_keys(bucket,folder)
        print(files)
```

I am able to list all the files

I want to download the files and and read to a pandas dataframe and once I run the below code I am getting the error - **ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden**

```
for file in files:
    buffer = BytesIO()
    client.download_fileobj(bucket, file, buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)
    obj = buffer.getvalue()
    print(obj)
```

I have all the bucket permissions from the source team, but not sure what is causing the issue. I want to read the files to a pandas dataframe to do some data clean up and load to destination s3 bucket.

Comment: Do your permissions include both s3:ListBucket and s3:GetObject for the relevant resources (the bucket and the object(s) respectively)?

Comment: @jarmod I gave the source team my role and they say they have given me ListBucket and GetObject permissions

Comment: I would test HeadObject and GetObject with the awscli using your provided credentials to take your app out of the picture. If these operations fail then talk to your source team to understand what you, or they, are doing wrong.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks I tested with AWS CLI and I am still getting the error.

Comment: @jarmod The source team says they have server side encryption enabled. I made this change client.download_fileobj(bucket, file, f, ExtraArgs={"SSECustomerKey": "aws:kms"}) , now I am getting 404 Bad request

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the ExtraArgs while downloading the file.
Because server-side encryption is enabled you need to make sure that the credentials, you are using to download the object, have access to the key used to encrypt the object.